# Convert old directive to higher version Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I convert a directive from angular 1.1.1 to angular 1.2.8
Kindly see the code here:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G9DuRp?p=preview)

Comment: Which problem did you run into when you tried?

Comment: Hi Ivarni, the output should be like this one, http://plnkr.co/edit/rX6BDVvtTR9mJSLdA1tG?p=preview but this link is using an old angular directive. I dont know how to convert it to 1.2.8

Comment: Most likely it will work fine with 1.2.8, have you even tried to run it with a newer version of angular?